# Python Selenium. Unable to locate elements

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying for hours to extract the text from an unknown number of elements on a website.
I uploaded 2 pictures so you can see similarities of the elements to identify them. They have the same class name, for example. The black underlined text is basically the text I want to extract.

I haven't even come to the step of extracting the text because I'm not able to even find the element.

Here is one of the things I've tried:

```
a=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pooVf")
print(a)
```

The result I got was '[]'.

I have also tried to use css selector

```
a=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.pooVf.prDW")
print(a)
```

Also got '[]'.

I have no clue how to add the html code as text. Everytime I tried it didn't work.

Comment: can you share ALL your code? Try adding a sleep like `time.sleep(5)` before `a=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pooVf")`. What selenium version do you use?

Comment: Can you please show us the lines that create `driver` and navigate it to the webpage?

Comment: Can you share that HTML in text format? Steps: `Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> then right click on the element you want to share the outer HTML - > select copy and then outer HTML`

Comment: You could use a CSS attribute selector to select only `a` tags who have `role="button"`, and whose immediate parent is a `div` where the `data-id` attribute is present. I haven't tested this, but something like `div[data-id] > a[role="button"]`.

Comment: @Prophet Its a pretty large project. I have added time.sleep(3) and I figured it should be enough since when I disable headless option it loads really quick. Idk how I can check my selenium version but it's the most recent one. I updated it yesterday. BTW All of my other code works. I'm able to find other elements and pay with them, just not this one.

Comment: @cruisepandey

`
<div class="t3RpAe prDW Rgstwe" dir="ltr">Hyundai i10, Servo, ZV, ABS, CD-Radio</div>
`

Comment: @DanielSchilling I can see when I disable headless, that it's going to the right website and when I put like time.sleep(200) I can even find the element myself by inspecting the site, so it's definitly present.

Comment: @PaulM. That sounds interesting. But do you have an idea, why the element can't be found? When I disable headless mode and inspect the element myself, I can put in the class name for example and find the right object.

Comment: Maybe that thread.sleep is necessary in your headless version as well. Maybe those elements are being added dynamically to the page by JavaScript, and do not exist when the page initially loads.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the function "`text`"?

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".....").text
```

Comment: Is that to extract the text? I was using getAttribute but it doesn't really matter cause the element can't be found. 

'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: `find_elements_by_css_selector(".pooVf")` will give you something to iterate over and get the individual attributes. Try this with a `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the element's **XPath** instead of its **CSS selector** or class name? I would've left this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: You may also want to add 5 seconds before trying to obtain the element.

Comment: yes, i tried a lot with xpath and putting class names in it, but I deleted the part.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.pooVf.prDW")
```

Instead of

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.pooVf.prDW")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Possibility: Dynamically added elements

Since the element exists when you manually inspect the DOM in a browser after a delay, but Selenium complains that it can't find it, I suspect that the element is being added dynamically by JavaScript. Selenium has tools for dealing with situations like these. See their docs on [waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

> These days, most of the web apps are using AJAX techniques. When a page is loaded by the browser, the elements within that page may load at different time intervals. This makes locating elements difficult: if an element is not yet present in the DOM, a locate function will raise an ElementNotVisibleException exception. Using waits, we can solve this issue. Waiting provides some slack between actions performed - mostly locating an element or any other operation with the element.

One option is to add the following line to make all of the `find` methods wait for a few seconds before giving up:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(5) # seconds
```

Don't make the delay too long, because you don't want to be waiting forever if the element really does not exist. Using Selenium's `wait` functionality is better than `time.sleep`. There's no point waiting once the element exists, but `sleep` has no way of knowing when this happens, whereas with `implicitly_wait`, the code should return as soon as the element is available.

## Possibility: Different session / cookies

Maybe the elements you are looking for depend on information (cookies, local storage, etc.) that is specific to your non-headless Chrome connection, and is not available to headless Chrome. It is like using two different browsers. Try using Chrome's Incognito mode and see if you can still find the elements when you inspect the DOM. If that reproduces the issue (the elements are missing), then that means you need to add additional lines to your Selenium code to replicate what you did in the browser: perhaps signing in with credentials on a login page, clicking some upload buttons, etc. All these are actions that need to be coded into your headless version - they can't depend on actions you manually performed in non-headless Chrome. Even then you may have difficulty with your selectors as written: `pooVf`, `t3RpAe`, `prDW`, and `Rgstwe` all look like fairly unique, unpredictable strings. If your sequence of actions (login, upload) results in different strings each time, then you will need to find these elements in a different way. Maybe one of their parent elements can be found more reliably.